# Complex Cascading in Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have three Django Models:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
     invited_by = models.ForeignKey("User")
     event = models.ForeignKey("Event", related_name="invitations")

class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(_('full name'))

class Event(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField()
     invitees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Now I want to delete the Event model if the invitees becomes empty.  So we have two users, Tim and Bob.  Tim invites Bob to the event.  So we have an event object and an invitation object.  Bob delete his account.  The invitation is deleted, but the event remains with no invitees.  I want this to automatically delete the event.  Any help or direction in the docs is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) the `delete` method on a model -- in this case `Invitation` -- to check whether the target `Event` no longer has any related invitations, and delete it appropriately (just make sure to call `super` somewhere in there, otherwise the actual deletion won't happen).

You could accomplish the same thing using the [`post_delete` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-delete).

However, it's important to note that these will only ever be called when calling `delete()` directly on a single instance, and not when using `delete()` on a queryset (e.g. `Invitation.objects.filter(...).delete()`). So if this is behavior you need to depend on, it's important to be very deliberate about how you delete objects.